# how to test licensed android app(.apk) from android market without purchasing?

Tags: android, testing

---

I want to test my paid licensed app without purchasing from android market because i want to check it once that the app can download by user or not.And to find any issues with the built(i integrate LVL to my app so i want to test it).

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish and go to the settings (left side, second icon from the top). There you can register 'Gmail accounts with testing access' for license testing. Just enter the emails of the test users that you want to use in a comma-separated list. Those are the google accounts on the test devices. They all will receive the license response you select just below that list.

Comment: For testing, the app should be publish or not?

Comment: It definitely works when testing an unpublished version of an app that has an old version in the market. Haven't tried with apps that have never been published. But the following sentence from the settings page suggests it then works only with the developer's account:

"The account owner (but not the other test accounts) will also get this response for applications that have not been uploaded to Google Play yet."

Comment: Hi,I have a small Question.i have to send the apk to that developer's account mail and to download it from that account.And we have to test it like that.I already run it from device by using eclipse it saying same thing that" purchase it from Google play store".my device is already sync with that account

Comment: I am sorry, but i am not sure i understand the question... make sure you have registered the app and use the same account for registration and testing.

Comment: Registered means to upload the APk file

Comment: You can add (register) a new application without uploading the apk.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: Ok, great! Please either mark my answer as accepted or answer with your solution if it was different.